# Selecting one of the options in the drop down list

Tags: javascript

I have a field which is called "Status"  and it is a drop down list,  I am writing a test, that I want it to select one of the options in the list. As you can see I have find the status field, now I do not know how to select one of the options in the drop down list.

```
var page = Sys.Browser("firefox").Page("myurl);
var statusBox = page.NativeWebObject.Find("name","Status","select");
```

This is the HTML:

```
<select name="Status" required="required" title="Status">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="In Preparation - Not Submitted">In Preparation -Not Submitted</option>
<option value="Submitted for Review">Submitted for Review</option>
<option value="Funded - In Progress">Funded - In Progress</option>
<option value="Completed">Completed</option>
<option value="Submitted - Denied Funding">Submitted - Denied Funding</option>
 <option value="Work Discontinued">Work Discontinued</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Writing a test with what exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `selected` manually or programatically to one of your `<option>` tags.

For instance:

```
<select name="Status" required="required" title="Status">
  <option value="In Preparation - Not Submitted" selected>In Preparation -Not Submitted</option>
</select>
```

You can read more about this in [MDN's option manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.But if I do that, then the option that I have added selected to, will be selected as default. Actually I am working with TestComplete, and writing test, so that when I run my test, it will go to the URl that I have mentioned. I have to say that the URL is a form, that usually users will fill it out, but when I run my test, all the fields will be filled out according to the value I have mentioned in the test I have written.So that is why I do not know what to  write so that when I run the test, one of the options got selected.